# How do Graduate Admissions Committees view an applicant from Industry?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, industry

At the time of writing this, I have been working for Raytheon Missile Systems (RMS) for about 2.5 years since graduating college.

Prior to graduation, I was on track to go a more academic route due to graduate work and independent study projects I was involved in related to computational mathematics. I ended up choosing to try out industry first, however, since I had no experience with it and wanted to know if this path would be preferable for me long term.

While I have been successful at RMS and used my computational math background to achieve a lot there, I don't think industry is where I want to stay and so I am now working on applications so I can pursue a PhD and more academic career.

Given my industry background, are there any common beliefs in academia, whether good or bad, about individuals from industry I should be aware of for the sake of my application? Is there anything I should strive to highlight or avoid in my application that would help me fare better in the application process?

**EDIT**:
My experience pre-RMS was largely in numerical analysis, optimization, and simulation, with emphasis in nonlinear systems of hyperbolic partial differential equations. One sample project, for example, was implementing a Space-Time Discontinuous Galerkin Finite Element code to tackle a system of Hyperbolic PDEs and doing validation and convergence studies to validate the theory. I also gained decent experience via independent studies and working at NASA JPL in computer vision. Other skills gained were in parallel computing using OpenMP and MPI.

At RMS, I have worked on clusters and have primarily developed and built codes in areas like numerical optimization, adaptive sampling of unknown functions, supervised machine learning, controls, bayesian estimation algorithms, and simulations.

In terms of research, I am planning to apply to computational math or computer science programs and hope to get involved in machine learning with emphasis in Reinforcement Learning for partially-observable Markov decision problems in continuous state and action spaces.

Comment: Generally the problematic part of this situation (for admissions committees) is having been away from academia for years. See e.g. [Usefulness of prior industry experience before entering grad school?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/120/11365), [Getting back into academics after an industry stint: what can I do while still in industry to improve my research profile?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55509/11365), [Is it hard to start a PhD programme after leaving to work in industry?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/3256/11365)

Comment: Also [Getting into gradschool from a “real job”](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/17383/11365), [How to secure recommendations and apply for PhD after having worked outside of academia for two years?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/14629/11365)

Comment: @ff524 Thank you for the reference links. They are providing some useful info for me to consider with my application.

Comment: Whether your industry experience works in your favor or not will mainly depend on whether the groups you are seeking to get into favor that type of experience: on one hand, research groups which have strong ties to industry will generally look positively on your relevant industry experience, while, on the other hand, research groups which are doing mainly theoretical work may not care about your industry experience as much. Perhaps edit your question to include the type of research you want to do?

Comment: @MadJack I added some of my background and the research area I am hoping to get involved in, if that can help with anything. I do think the resources provided by ff524 help me answer the general question I was looking to have answered.

Comment: @MadJack Though I will note, any specific feedback about what I am interested in getting involved in with respect to research would be very appreciated as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several considerations that may make it difficult for you.  Here are a few based on gut instinct:

1) You are an 'outsider' - the traditional route of undergraduate to graduate school often entails nurturing relationships with other academics at your home institution and abroad.  Those relationships help grease the wheels when it comes to letters of support.  But, this can be overcome. Perhaps you already maintain relationships with academic circles.  Failing that, strong letters from higher-ups at a place like RMS are probably just as noteworthy.

2) From the PI's perspective, taking a graduate student is a long-term investment. You would occupy a spot that could be offered to someone else, so in addition to promising productivity, PI's generally prefer the person have the goal of continuing on and pursuing an academic life.  Since you've been in industry, there is always the fear that at some point, you'll simply abdicate and return to industry.

I think you can spin your industry experience 'narrative' to your advantage.  First, you can stress that your time in industry did not meet your needs for academic development.  In other words, only academics provides the platform to realize your highly technical goals.  Second, people in industry usually have a very strong work ethic and know how to get things done; something that is often lacking in new graduate students.  You might consider documenting just how productive you have been.

Comment: I am not sure I understand (1). The OP works in industry for only about 2.5 years since graduating college. He did not indicate he would have problem getting recommendation letter from the college he graduated from. Letters from RMS can serve as a plus.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your comments fit with the approach of my current Statement of Purpose. At the moment, I talk about how industry doesn't really provide the challenging work I seek to do, while academia does and how that makes me desire to go down a more academic path. In terms of letters of rec, I have pretty good relationships with some professors at school via projects I did under them, so I think I should get some strong letters from them. I also have a strong letter from a very senior and successful engineer from RMS with a PhD, so I hope that carries weight.